# Login With different Template - Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have this app.component.html that works well for all pages EXCEPT the login (I dont want nav,sidebar nor footer)

```
<app-nav></app-nav>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div class="container">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

module.ts

```
const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'login', component:LoginComponent},
  {path: 'dashboard', component:EnvironmentComponent},
  {path: 'docker', component:DockerComponent}
];
```

How do I remove it??

Comment: you do not want what?

Comment: I dont want nav,sidebar nor footer in the login page

Comment: this should be very used right? I mean... Usually the login page is totally different from the other pages

Comment: upvote if the answer helped

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle this with the *ngIf based on the url that you are currently in.

```
<app-sidebar *ngIf="isLoginPage()"></app-sidebar>
```

and then,

```
isLoginPage(): boolean {
        const check = this.router.url.indexOf('/login');
        if (check) {
            return false;
        }
    return true;
}
```